# Google Play IAP hacking?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

So i've been getting a lot of IAP purchases which don't reflect inside my google play reports. So i am storing the orderid from the purchases and i go the following in the last day

```
7538359222329310727.1090367698540284
7904471098955901363.4048785862167884
8091363312980047305.5713766357559515
8199155201581655906.8717778176404042
GPA.3375-0549-3230-07005
GPA.3398-3364-3034-12218
```

Are the non GPA order id valid? I know that at some point that was the format, but now all of my valid orders in report are having GPA in front. Also, not even the GPA ones are inside my reports. There is no way that an incomplete purchase generate an order id right? So my guess they somehow hack it?

I don't have any verification in place right now, probably i will add it. Just wanna make sure that is the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are invalid IDs, all current IDs start with `GPA.`. Try to also store the result code with each order to see if you're only recording purchases that Google Play actually reported as 'payment succeeded' to your app.